# Prompt for password when sending

Tags: vba, outlook

I want Outlook to prompt for a password or some sort of authentication on all outgoing mail items, because someone keeps sending on behalf on my account.

I have written:

```
If Omail.SendUsingAccount = "My Domain Email account typed here" Then

    Sub password()
    Dim pass As String
    pass = InputBox("Enter Password")
    If pass <> "thepassword" Then Exit Sub

End Sub
```

This doesn't work. After I have the correct code can I then just insert that into a custom action rule?

Comment: Perhaps it is a delegate issue. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Allow-someone-else-to-manage-your-mail-and-calendar-41c40c04-3bd1-4d22-963a-28eafec25926

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below code:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
 prompt$ = "Enter Password to Send Mail"

Dim pass As String
    pass = InputBox("Enter Password")
If pass <> "yourpwd" Then
Cancel = True
 End If
End Sub
```

Its tested and its working fine.

make sure you have enabled macro from trust centre.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a VBA macro where you can handle the [ItemSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076.aspx) event of the Application class which is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an Inspector (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the Send method for an Outlook item, such as MailItem, is used in a program.

For example:

```
Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application 

Public Sub Initialize_handler() 
 Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application 
End Sub 

Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean) 
 Dim prompt As String 
 prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?" 
 If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then 
  Cancel = True 
 End If 
End Sub
```

You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.